# Performing weighted overlay analysis in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, weighted-overlay

I want to prepare a landslide zone map using weighted overlay analysis. Is there a tool in MapInfo to do weighted overlay as in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does. Use 'Surface Menu' in 'Discover' tab menu to create grid from scattered elevation point (or DEM could be more helpful or more detailed imagery griding data). Further 'method' just follow the menu subsequently for statistical/geostatistical analyses.

Comment: It should be noted that the "Discover" menu does not appear unless you have purchased Encom Discover.